# Disable certain buttons when you click on a specific button

Tags: javascript, button, extjs

I have 3 buttons and when I click on button 3, I want button 1 and 2 to be disabled. I am able to do that. When I try and set another listener for when button 2 is clicked on to disable button 1 and 3, it does not work and properly. It seems like it might be in some sort of loop. Here is my code listed below:

```
{
                                text: 'Button 1',
                                name: 'button1',
                                cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
                                listeners: {"click": function (){
                                    Ext.getCmp("button2").disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp("button3").disable();
                                    }
                                },
                                icon: 'public/images/edit.gif'
                            },{
                                text: 'Button 2',
                                name: 'button2',
                                cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
                                listeners: {"click": function (){
                                    Ext.getCmp("button1").disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp("button3").disable();
                                    }
                                },
                                icon: 'public/images/edit.gif'
                            },{
                                text: 'Button 3',
                                name: 'button3',
                                cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
                                listeners: {"click": function (){
                                    Ext.getCmp("button1").disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp("button2").disable();
                                    }
                                },
                                icon: 'public/images/edit.gif'
                            }
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.getCmp is for the `id` attribute.  Your buttons have the `name` attribute, change `name` to `id` and your example should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i click a button and it disables the button, I am fine with it disabling for good (unless the user refreshes the page). But what happens is that when I have all of those listeners, the not matter which button I click on the other buttons will not disappear for whatever reason.

Comment: I just noticed the real issue after I read your comment, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is [toggleGroup](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-toggleGroup).

Answer (score 0):

I used alternate way but I am not sure will fit your needs. Try below if it's make sense for you.

- I had create an array out of the scope to keep button id's.
- Then made a function to disable buttons except clicked.
- I used button group to organize buttons

```
var buttons = new Array();

var disableButtons = function (btn) {
    // here it is to query button group by name
    var btns = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('buttongroup, [name=btnGroup]');
    var count = btns.length;

    for (var i = 1, x = 0; i < count; i++, x++) {
        this.buttons[x] = btns[i].id;
    }

    // this is the tricky part, disable all buttons except the clicked
    var index = this.buttons.indexOf(btn);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.buttons.splice(index, 1);
    }

    Ext.Array.each(buttons, function (name) {
        Ext.getCmp(name).disable();
    })
}

// in any case, I created a function to enable all button status
// just add an other button in the scene and call this function
var enableButtons = function () {
    Ext.Array.each(buttons, function (name) {
        Ext.getCmp(name).enable();
    });
    // The following line necessary to keep array clean when user wants to disable
    // buttons again. The best way to empty an array, just set length to '0'
    buttons.length = 0;
}


// I used these functions for window component. When user click 'ADD' button, 
// buttons listener calls this function
{
text: 'EKLE',
scale: 'medium',
disabled: true,
width: 100,
margin: '0 9 0 0',
cls: 'btn-article-save',
id: 'btnArticleSave',
name: '_btnArticle',
listeners: {
    click: function () {
        var sel = Ext.getCmp('article-grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        Ext.each(sel, function (item, index) {
            arrArticle.push(item);
        });

        arrArticleStore.load();
        Ext.getCmp('articles-grid').getView().bindStore(arrArticleStore);
        Ext.getCmp('articles-grid').show();

        var alevel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=artLevel]');
        var avalue = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=artValue]');

        var artActions = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < alevel.length; i++) {
            artActions[i] = {'LEVELS': alevel[i].value, 'VALUES': avalue[i].value}
        }
        var count = winArticle.down('fieldset[id=article-fieldset]').items.items.length;
        for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            var container = 'artContainer' + i;
            winArticle.down('fieldset[id=article-fieldset]').remove(container);
        }

        var qry = winArticle.query();
        for (var i = 0; i < qry.length; i++) {
            if (qry[i].xtype === 'textfield') {
                var txt = qry[i].id;
                Ext.getCmp(txt).reset();
                articles.loadData([], false);
            }
        }

        var _name = this.name;
        disableButtons(_name);
    }
}
```

}